# Overflow Error in MS Access 2007 Query that applies grouping to >81,000 records

Tags: ms-access-2007, overflow, grouping

I have a query that groups on three fields in order to calculate an Avg and StDev for a fourth field.  When ungrouped, the query returns >81,000 records.  The query has been working fine until recently when the number of records more than doubled.  Now I get an 'Overflow' message.  If I take grouping off it works fine.

I have looked on various sites for the causes of Overflow errors and have not seen any that address whether there is a point at which something gets too complex for Access to handle.

Am I missing something?  Any suggestions?

Comment: What DataType is the field you are storing your answer in?

Comment: Also, please update your question to show the actual SQL that you are trying to use. For what it's worth I just ran a query that calculated the `Avg()` and `StDev()` on a million rows and Access didn't complain.

Comment: @Sico The source DataType is Number with field size Double.  The query I am having trouble with is a calculated field called MAG which is derived from two columns with DataType = Number.  The query in question is a subquery of the one that does the MAG calculation.

Comment: @GordThompson This is the SQL for the query  SELECT Z1_LIST_AND_GROUP.TIER, Z1_LIST_AND_GROUP.MEASUREMENT, Z1_LIST_AND_GROUP.[STAT TEST], Avg(Z1_LIST_AND_GROUP.MAG) AS AvgOfMAG, StDev(Z1_LIST_AND_GROUP.MAG) AS StDevOfMAG
FROM Z1_LIST_AND_GROUP
GROUP BY Z1_LIST_AND_GROUP.TIER, Z1_LIST_AND_GROUP.MEASUREMENT, Z1_LIST_AND_GROUP.[STAT TEST];

Comment: We need to see the subquery. Do you want to update your question with all of the queries in question. It makes it easier for us to follow what's happening. The question area formats your SQL to make it easier to read